# Shopware 6 visibilities and categories are empty in api

Tags: php, symfony, shopware, shopware6

I created a plugin for Shopware 6 and I tried to create multiple products. Before I created some products, I added some demo products in the administration panel. But if I read the variables of those products, the fields visibilities and categories are empty, but in the administration panel where were some values in them. I don't understand why in the administration panel it can be shown and in the plugin it was empty. The code was running in a command for bin/console.

```
$context = Context::createDefaultContext();
$products = $this->productRepository->search(new Criteria(), $context);
foreach ($products as $p => $product) {
    $product->get('visibilities'); // -> empty in command but not in admin panel
    $product->get('categories'); // -> empty in command but not in admin panel
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shopware 6, the visibility and categories of a product are typically not loaded by default when you retrieve products from the database using the ProductRepository. This is because Shopware uses a concept called "associations" to lazy-load related data for performance reasons. This means that when you retrieve a product, its related data like categories and visibility might not be loaded until explicitly requested.

To ensure that the visibility and categories data are loaded for each product in your code, you can use the addAssociation method to specify which associations you want to load for each product. Here's how you can modify your code to load the visibility and categories for each product:

```
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Context;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Filter\EqualsFilter;

$context = Context::createDefaultContext();
$criteria = new Criteria();

// Add associations for visibility and categories
$criteria->addAssociation('visibilities');
$criteria->addAssociation('categories');

// Perform the product search with the updated criteria
$products = $this->productRepository->search($criteria, $context);

foreach ($products as $product) {
    // Now, the 'visibilities' and 'categories' should be loaded for each product
    $visibilities = $product->get('visibilities');
    $categories = $product->get('categories');
    
    // You can work with $visibilities and $categories here
}
```

By adding the associations for 'visibilities' and 'categories' to the criteria, you instruct SW to load these related entities along with the products when you perform the search. This should populate the fields with the data you expect.

Comment: You can also take a look at the docs here: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/reading-data#associations

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy